# The way of defining class methods without the need of keeping the order of calling them

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns, methods

Hi I have a class which includes two methods.
One of which is to initialize session , another one is for redirect the web page
I ve written the class such that it can be called repeatedly.

```
  $obj->setSession(key,value)->redirect(url);
```

In this mode , the session is firstly initialized and then it redirects to the next page. 
But if it's written like this

```
  $obj->redirect(url)->setSession(key,value);
```

It just redirects to the defined location qnd the session is not initialized anymore .. 
It s cuz when the resirect method is called, the page changes promptly and it causes the second method not to be called ..
Is there any way to be able to call methods repeatedly without the need of considering their order ?

Comment: I would say yes, but you would have to add a lot more code to check if conditions you want are true or false

Comment: Quick question, is `setSession` optional or do you always need to call it before redirecting?

Comment: that moethod is optional

Answer (score 0):

When I usually face that issue, I add a method in the `$obj` object called `render()` or `done()` or something to that effect that checks all the flags I might have defined previously. One of those flags might be a `header` flag, which is what a `redirect` method usually does `header(Location: $yourDestUrl)`.

So you end up with something like:

```
$obj->redirect(url)->setSession(key,value)->render();
```

Comment: using a render method makes the code longer and i have seen these kind of method invokings many times in laravel

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method such as `redirect` or `setSession`, put those actions in a "stack" as a property of you class.

Then, when all your methods are called, call a method called `exec` (for example) that will execute all the actions in the "stack".

Here is a base class based on this idea using magic methods:

```
class Stack {

    private $_stack = array();

    public function __call($method, $args) {

        // Adding method to stack
        $this->_stack[$method] = $args;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {

        // Checks if method is in stack
        return isset($this->_stack[$name];
    }

    public function exec() {

        // setSession is executed first
        if (isset($this->setSession))
            call_user_func_array('setSessionMethod', $this->_stack['setSession']);


        // redirect is executed second
        if (isset($this->redirect))
            call_user_func_array('redirectMethod', $this->_stack['redirect']);

    }
}
```

To use this class, you would do:

```
$stack = new Stack;
$stack->redirect('arg')
      ->setSession('arg1', 'arg2')
      ->exec();
```

Comment: using a exec method makes the code longer and i have seen these kind of method invokings many times in laravel

Comment: @user3754884 Well, there isn't any other way of doing what you're asking, the methods will always be called in the order they're written. So if your `redirect` method exits the execution before `setSession` is called, it will redirect your page and later calls to methods won't be executed.  Moreover, the "stack method" isn't messy, it only adds one required call to the `exec` method, and adds a few lines to your class, but it will ensure the execution is done in the order you want no matter in which order the user code calls the methods.